# sed command to select certain number of lines from a file

Tags: shell, sed, aix

I am trying to split huge files each of which will contain around say 30k of lines.
I found it can be done using    sed -n 'from_line,to_line p'    command but it is working fine if i have line numbers but here in my case i am using two variable and i am getting error for that.

here is script which i am using.

```
k=1
for i in `ls final*`
do
    count=`wc -l $i|awk '{print $1}'`

    marker1=1
    marker2=30000
    no_of_files=$(( count/30000 ))

    #echo $no_of_files
    no_of_files=$(( no_of_files+1 ))

    while [[ no_of_files -ne 0 ]];do

        if [[ $marker2 -gt $count ]];then
            sed -n '$marker1,$count p' $i > purge$k.txt
        else
            sed -n '$marker1,$marker2 p' $i > purge$k.txt
            marker1=$(( marker2+1 ))
            marker2=$(( marker2+30000 ))
        fi

        no_of_files=$(( no_of_files-1 ))
        k=$(( k+1 ))
    done 
done
```

I am getting below error while running the script.

```
sed: $marker1,$marker2 p is not a recognized function.
sed: $marker1,$marker2 p is not a recognized function.
sed: $marker1,$marker2 p is not a recognized function.
sed: $marker1,$marker2 p is not a recognized function.
sed: $marker1,$marker2 p is not a recognized function.
sed: $marker1,$marker2 p is not a recognized function.
sed: $marker1,$count p is not a recognized function.
```

Comment: You are using single quotes so the string is taken literally.

Comment: If you're splitting a file, use [`split`](http://man.cx/split)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesnt work probably because you use variables in ''

try to change sed commands as follow

```
sed -n "$marker1,$count p"
```

or better is  this

```
sed -n '/'$marker1'/,/'$count'/p'
```

Comment: Why is last one better?

Answer (score 0):

Some small changes.
Use double quote in `sed`.  Do not use old back tics, use parentheses.
Change `k=$(( k+1 ))` to `((k++))`.

```
k=1
for i in $(ls final*)
    do
    count=$(wc -l <$i)
    marker1=1
    marker2=30000
    no_of_files=$(( count/30000 ))
    #echo $no_of_files
    (( no_of_files++ ))
    while [[ no_of_files -ne 0 ]];do
        if [[ $marker2 -gt $count ]];then
            sed -n "$marker1,$count p" $i > purge$k.txt
        else
            sed -n "$marker1,$marker2 p" $i > purge$k.txt
            marker1=$(( marker2+1 ))
            marker2=$(( marker2+30000 ))
        fi
        (( no_of_files-- ))
    (( k++ ))
    done 
done
```

This `wc -l $i|awk '{print $1}'` could be used like this:

```
awk 'END {print NR}' $i
```

or

```
wc -l < $i
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, but when we are simply executing the sed command it works with normal ' and when i am using it in script it doesn't work. Are there any specific cases where we need to use " instead of '. if you could expalin bit in detail will be helpful thanks

Comment: @GauravParek Its like Jidder commented.  When you need to expand a value from a variable (get the number out of it), you need double quote `"`. With single quote `'` `sed` does see the text.  Example.  `i=5`. `echo "$i"` gives `5`, but `echo '$i'` returns `$i`.  This will be the same in execution or in a bash program.

Comment: You can directly do `wc -l <$i` to get just the number of lines. What of course is quite inefficient is `cat $i | wc -l`.

Comment: Note that the `awk` approach is very inefficient. Done a test with `seq 10000000 > a` and it's about 6 times slower, because you are unnecessarily reading the file, while `wc` does not (I guess!).

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, you have your shell variables inside single quotes so they are not being expanded.  But you are using the wrong tool.  What you are doing creates N files using N passes.  `split -l 30000 "$i"` will split the file into 30,000 line pieces called xaa, xab, ...  You can tell split what to call the xaa files too.